# how to move an imported .db file within xcode directly to an iphone

Tags: ios, c, xcode, fopen

I want to replace an existing sms.db file in my iphone with a modified sms.db file that has been imported into the xcode project.

I have a function below, cp() that takes "from" and "to" params.  I want to execute it like this:

```
cp('/path/within/xcode/project/sms-modified.db', '/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db');
```

how can i modify the below function to take the sms.db imported in xcode and replace the sms.db within my phone?

```
int cp(const char *from, const char *to) {
    int fd_to, fd_from;
    char buf[4096];
    ssize_t nread;
    int saved_errno;

    fd_from = open(from, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_from < 0)
        return -1;

    fd_to = open(to, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
    if (fd_to < 0)
        goto out_error;

    while (nread = read(fd_from, buf, sizeof buf), nread > 0)
    {
        char *out_ptr = buf;
        ssize_t nwritten;

        do {
            nwritten = write(fd_to, out_ptr, nread);

            if (nwritten >= 0)
            {
                nread -= nwritten;
                out_ptr += nwritten;
            }
            else if (errno != EINTR)
            {
                goto out_error;
            }
        } while (nread > 0);
    }

    if (nread == 0)
    {
        if (close(fd_to) < 0)
        {
            fd_to = -1;
            goto out_error;
        }
        close(fd_from);

        /* Success! */
        return 0;
    }

    out_error:
    saved_errno = errno;

    close(fd_from);
    if (fd_to >= 0)
        close(fd_to);

    errno = saved_errno;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: fopen?  What programming language are you talking about?  C?  PHP?  Who's said that you could get direct access to a macOS file from an iOS app?

Comment: using C.  if I import the file into the project, how can i get it from the project to the phone?

Comment: @ElTomato i've updated the question

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Your question is clearly about modifying a C function, so why use the objective-c and swift tags?

Comment: sry, didn't know that actually, never built an xcode project before

Answer (score 0):

> how can i modify the below function to take the sms.db imported in xcode and replace the sms.db within my phone?

You can't. Your iPhone is "sandboxed". It cannot "see" your computer.

Comment: What if the sms.db file is imported into the project file? surely, it must be possible to get that file into my iphone right?

Comment: It is possible to build it into the app. It is not possible to move it from the computer to the phone thru the file system as your `cp` function would do.

Comment: i see, maybe i should've been clearer in my question with the .db already imported into xcode